# Marker Clusterer not Clustering / TypeError

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, typeerror, markerclusterer

This question pertains to the Google Maps Marker Clusterer. I don't know if my placement of the marker clusterer is off, or what, but it's not coming through. I get the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Can not read property of 'icon' of undefined.`
This error does not come through when the marker clusterer code is not in place.

Link to page for reference: http://exilebrewing.com/locations/

Does anyone understand why this is happening? Any insight is appreciated!

```
<?php // Index template
get_header(); ?>


<div class="twelve column">
  <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
      <div class="intro"> </div>
      <?php the_content(); ?>
      <div>
      <header class="clearfix"></header>
      <div id="mapcanvas"></div>
     <?php
      // For creating multiple, customized loops.
      // http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query
      $custom_query = new WP_Query('post_type=locations'); // exclude category 9
      while($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post(); ?>
         <?php if(get_field('link')): ?>
            <div>
              <?php while(has_sub_field('link')): ?>
                <div>
                    <p><?php the_sub_field('url'); ?></p>
                </div>
              <?php endwhile; ?>
            </div>
          <?php endif; ?>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
      <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // reset the query ?>
      <?php
        function get_single_term($post_id, $taxonomy)
        {
          $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post_id, $taxonomy);
          if(!is_wp_error($terms)) {
            return '<a href="'.get_term_link($terms[0]->slug, $taxonomy).'">'.$terms[0]->name.'</a>';
          }
        }

        $i = 0;

        // For creating multiple, customized loops.
        // http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query
        $custom_query = new WP_Query('post_type=location&posts_per_page=-1');
        while($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post();

          $title = get_the_title(); // Location title
          $map   = get_field('location'); // ACF location contains address and coordinates
          $terms = strip_tags( get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'distributors', '', ' & ' )); // Get distributor terms and rm links
          $info  = '<strong>' . $title . '</strong><br>' . $map['address']; // Info window content
          $link = get_field('link');
          if($link){
            $info .= '<br><a href="http://'. $link .'">'. $link .'</a>';
          }
          $location[$i][0] = $title; // Store the post title
          $location[$i][1] = $map['coordinates']; // Store the ACF coordinates
          $location[$i][2] = json_encode($info); // Store info window content
          $location[$i][3] = strip_tags( get_single_term( $post->ID, 'distributors' )); // Get first term for marker icon

          $i ++;
        endwhile; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // reset the query ?>

        <script type="text/javascript">
          function initialize() {
            var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.583013,-93.63701500000002);
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                var styles = [
              {
                stylers: [
                  { saturation: -99.9 }
                ]
              }
            ];
            // Create a new StyledMapType object, passing it the array of styles,
            // as well as the name to be displayed on the map type control.
            var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles, {name: 'exile'});
            // Create a map object, and include the MapTypeId to add
            // to the map type control.
            var mapOptions = {
              mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
              center: myLatLng,
              zoom: 14,
              disableDefaultUI: false,
              scrollwheel: true,
              draggable: true
            };
            // Display a map on the page
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapcanvas'), mapOptions);
                //var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map);
                map.setTilt(45);
                //Associate the styled map with the MapTypeId and set it to display.
                map.mapTypes.set('exile', styledMap);
                map.setMapTypeId('exile');
            // Marker icons
                typeObject = {
                  "Others" : {
                    "icon" : new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://exilebrewing.com/site/img/beer-mug.png', new google.maps.Size(18,26), new google.maps.Point(0,0), new google.maps.Point(9,26)),
                    "shadow" : new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/shadow50.png', new google.maps.Size(40,34))
                  }

                }

            var markers = [

          ];
          for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
          var dataPhoto = data.photos[i];
          var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(dataPhoto.latitude, dataPhoto.longitude);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: latLng
          });
          markers.push(marker);
          }
          var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);


          // Info Window Content
          var infoWindowContent = [
            ["<strong>Exile Brewing Co.</strong><br>1514 Walnut Street, Des Moines"],
            <?php
            if (count($location)>0) {
              foreach ($location as $key => $value){
                if ($key < (count($location)-1)) {
                  echo '[' . $location[$key][2] . '], ' . "\n";
                } else {
                  echo '[' . $location[$key][2] . ']';
                }
              }
            }
            ?>
          ];


          // Display multiple markers on a map
          var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;

         // Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map
         for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
            var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]); // ACF coordinates
            var icon = typeObject[markers[i][3]]['icon'];
            var shadow = typeObject[markers[i][3]]['shadow'];
            bounds.extend(position);
              marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: position,
                map: map,
                title: markers[i][0],
                icon: icon,
                shadow: shadow
              });

           // Allow each marker to have an info window
           google.maps.event.addListener(markers, 'click', (function(markers, i) {
            return function() {
              infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
              infoWindow.open(map, markers);
            }
          })(markers, i));
          // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
          //map.fitBounds(bounds);
          }
          // Override our map zoom level once our fitBounds function runs (Make sure it only runs once)
          var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
             this.setZoom(15);
             google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
             });
        };

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
      </script>

  <footer class="clearfix"></footer>
<?php endwhile;?>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pushing your google.maps.Markers onto the array of markers (which are not google.maps.Markers.  MarkerClusterer expects an array of google.maps.Markers.

In the global scope:

```
var gmarkers = [];
```

when you create the marker push it onto this new array (*not* onto the end of the markers array):

```
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: latLng
      });
      gmarkers.push(marker);
```

Use the new array to initialize the marker clusterer:

```
      var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, gmarkers);
```

Comment: Thanks! So I need to create another array, not substitute this with the current one, right?

Comment: Yes to submit to the MarkerClusterer, if you want to do it that way.  You could also add each marker individually to the clusterer as you create the marker, but that is a bigger change. If you just want to make it work, you need to put the markers in a separate new array to pass in to the MarkerClusterer constructor.